# How to reduce the number of for loops

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures

How I can improve this code,I am getting accurate output but it seems little long and unnecessary operations. Any Suggestion.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        a.add(1);
        a.add(2);

        List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        b.add(3);
        b.add(5);
        System.out.println(test(5, a, b));
    }

    public static long test(int n, List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
        // Write your code here
        long retCnt = 0;
        List<String> enemy = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            enemy.add(a.get(i) + "" + b.get(i));
        }



        String tempstr = "";
        int tempj = 1;
        for (int m = 1; m <= n; m++) {
            int temp = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                tempstr = "";
                for (int j = tempj; j <= temp; j++) {
                    tempstr += j;
                }
                temp++;
                if (!"".equalsIgnoreCase(tempstr)) {
                    if (isValidGroup(enemy, tempstr)) {
                        retCnt++;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            tempj++;
        }

        return retCnt;
    }

    public static boolean isValidGroup(List<String> enemy, String group) {
        for (int i = 0; i < enemy.size(); i++) {
            if (group.trim().toUpperCase().contains(String.valueOf(enemy.get(i).charAt(0)).toUpperCase())&& group.trim().contains(String.valueOf(enemy.get(i).charAt(1)).toUpperCase())) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Short description of the problem statement.

I have a enemy list , That is contains pair such as 13 and 25 from the input array list and b respectively.
I have a number n call 5 , I have to generate possible permutations which should be not part of the enemy list.

Please comment if further clarifications needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is slow. If n was 100, your code would require more than 100 million computations to execute.

The whole test function can however be executed in O(N) with some binomial math and if you directly jump above the indices where invalid numbers are. It can also be done in O(N^2) with the very simple algorithm below.

First thing I would do to save memory and code is to delete the variables tempj and temp, because you can use variables m and i for doing the same work and those have always the same values associated and they have to be created anyways for doing the right amount of iterations.

Also another useful thing to notice is that tempj will sometimes (in around half of all iterations to be more exact) be bigger than temp. In all those occasions, you won't be finding any valid permutations, because j iterates only from temp to tempj in **increasing** order. In other words, half of the computations are useless.

Tempstr can be precomputed.

Imagine tempj was 1 and temp was 3. J will then do 2 iterations from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3. J has reached temp, so you add one to temp. Temp is now 4 and Tempj is still 1.

Now J has to do the exact previous 2 steps to get from 1 to 3, and then an additional one to get to 4, where temp is. You can skip those previous 2 steps because you already know what tempstr will look like after them. Instead of resetting j, keep increasing it as temp increases.

Here is a snippet of the O(N^2) (without taking into account isValidGroup()'s complexity, which can be easily optimized using an array of booleans, where you mark the invalid positions in N^2)

```
String tempstr = "";
for(int start = 1; start <= n; start++) {
    tempstr = "";
    for(int end = start; end <= n; end++) {
        tempstr += end;
        if(isValidGroup(enemy, tempstr)) {
            retCnt++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for very well explanation, But I am afraid still i am getting time out for some of the test cases.